# Connecting Orion Context Broker from another machine

Tags: fiware-orion

I can't connect to ContextBroker from another machine, even a machine in the same LAN.

Accessing by ssh without any problem

```
ssh geezar@192.168.1.115
```

and then

```
curl localhost:1026/statistics
```

the terminal shows the statistics, all right

```
<orion>
  <xmlRequests>3</xmlRequests>
  <jsonRequests>1</jsonRequests>
  <updates>1</updates>
  <versionRequests>1</versionRequests>
  <statisticsRequests>2</statisticsRequests>
  <uptime_in_secs>84973</uptime_in_secs>
  <measuring_interval_in_secs>84973</measuring_interval_in_secs>
</orion>
```

But when I try without ssh connection...

```
curl 192.168.1.115:1026/statistics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.1.115 port 1026: No route to host
```

Even, I routed the port 1026 to that machine (192.168.1.115) on the router configuration, and tried to access from my public IP, the result is the same, failed to connect

I think I am missing something, but.. what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable causes of this problem are:

- Something in the host (e.g a firewall or security group) is blocking the incoming connection
- Something in the client (e.g a firewall) is blocking the outcoming connection
- There is some other network issue is causing the connection problem.

**EDIT:** in GNU/Linux system, iptables is usually used as firewall. It can be disabled typically running `iptables -F`.

Comment: That's it ! Needed to open port on the firewall