# IDAS not connecting to the ContextBroker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

i'm having a problem sending the mesurements to the contextBroker.
I have the ContextBroker running on a CentOS virtual machine. On another CentOS virtual machine i'm setting the figway config.ini file with the host=/*ContextBroker Virtual Machine Host IP*/ and Port=1026. When i send mesurements to my ContextBroker:

```
python2.7 SendObservation.py Bus1 't|1'
```

it simply doesn't stick the values to the entity. It gives me a code:200 but the response is just blank.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Even when i do from one VM to another (to the one where the contextBroker is running) the command:

```
GET *ip*:1026/version
```

, it returns nothing.

**UPDATE:**

Running

```
GET localhost:1026/version
```

works. Returns what's supose to return.

Comment: What about running `GET localhost:1026/version` in the same machine where Orion is running? Does it work? Please, include that information in your question post.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I answered your question by updating the post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be similar to the one described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254295/connecting-orion-context-broker-from-another-machine). The most probable causes of Orion connection problems are:

- Something in the Orion host (e.g a firewall or security group) is blocking the incoming connection
- Something in the client host (e.g a firewall) is blocking the outcoming connection
- There is some other network issue is causing the connection problem.

Comment: It seems that way but i forwoard the 1026 and the 443 ports and even when that didn't work i also deactivated the firewall. Still nothing... I can ping the ip adresses from the host to the client and vice-versa.

Comment: Is Orion deployed in a FIWARE Lab VM? Has you checkeck that port 1026 is open in the associated security group?

Comment: I deployted my own Orion ContextBroker instance (CentOS 6.6 provided by you :) I opened the ports by commandline also...

Comment: Are you running CentOS 6.6 in a physical hosts or as VM inside a physical host (e.g. using VirtualBox)?

Comment: I'm running exactly on VirtualBox.

Comment: If the firewall *inside* VMs has been disabled in both ends, I'd recommend to check VirtualBox documentation in order to see if some network configuration is affecting. However, note that VirtualBox is a bit out of our scope ;)

Comment: Ok Fermín maybe it's somekind of misconfiguration in the VM network or a mistake that i made of some sort. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Now i have the same problem in a physical host. But i think it's because of the Fiware-Service. I'm not sure if i'm doing it right... Can you please provide me some documentation on How to create a service?

Comment: Given that Fiware-Service is not directly related with the topic of this question, let's deal with it in a separately for the sake of clearness. Could you create a new question for that, please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using the OpenIoT service, I have disabled the firewall on my physical host, and i'm having the same problem as i previously explained.. don't know what's happening...