# Create entity in a service using IDAS and ContextBroker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

So [I'm having some problems connection virtual devices to the contextBroker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751664/idas-not-connecting-to-the-contextbroker/29769240?noredirect=1#comment47783992_29769240)  and i thing it's because of the Fiware-Service. I don't want to use the OpenIoT (even though that didn't worked for me either). I didn't manage to find any documentation about service creation and maybe i'm creating it wrong.

I did `Python CreateService bus_auto 4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov`and i'm not sure it returns me 201. I updated the config.ini file to work on MY service but when i send the observations it doesn't change the value of the entity on the contextBroker

I'm now running it in

My config.ini file:

```
[user]
# Please, configure here your username at FIWARE Cloud and a valid Oauth2.0 TOKEN for your user (you can use get_token.py to obtain a valid TOKEN).
username=
token=NULL

[contextbroker]
host=127.0.0.1
port=1026
OAuth=no
# Here you need to specify the ContextBroker database you are querying.
# Leave it blank if you want the general database or the IDAS service if you are looking for IoT devices connected by you.
fiware_service=bus_auto

[idas]
host=130.206.80.40
adminport=5371
ul20port=5371
OAuth=no
# Here you need to configure the IDAS service your devices will be sending data to.
# By default the OpenIoT service is provided.
fiware-service=bus_auto
fiware-service-path=/
apikey=4jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov

[local]
#Choose here your System type. Examples: RaspberryPI, MACOSX, Linux, ...
host_type=CentOS
# Here please add a unique identifier for you. Suggestion: the 3 lower hexa bytes of your Ethernet MAC. E.g. 79:ed:af
# Also you may use your e-mail address.
host_id=db:00:ff
```

I'm using the python script GetEntity.py:

```
python2.7 GetEntity.py bus_auto_2
```

I also tried using a python script that i created:

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:1026'
QUERY_URL = BASE_URL+'/v1/queryContext'

HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

QUERY_EXAMPLE = {
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "bus_auto_2",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1"
        }
    ]
}


def post(url, data):
    """"""
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, HEADERS)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print post(UPDATE_URL, json.dumps(UPDATE_EXAMPLE))
    print post(QUERY_URL, json.dumps(QUERY_EXAMPLE))
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the command or mechanism you are using to check the entity at ContextBroker? Thanks!

Comment: The answer was edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the service is well created and actually I see one device defined within it.

I have even successfully sent an observation (t|23) bus_auto_2 device

Later, I check in the ContextBroker this entity: "thing:bus_auto_2" and I see the latest observation I sent.

Did you update in the config.ini file the FIWARE_SERVICE both at ContextBroker and IDAS sections ?

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as you can check by my edited answer that the service is well written :)

Comment: Hi Diego, I have tried with: > python SendObservation.py bus_auto_2 ‘p|1’1
> python GetEntity.py thing:bus_auto_2 I think you are not querying the right entity.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't quite understand your question. I have the contextBroker running on my localhost (so as mongoDB).

Comment: Diego, I have found it. All your entities are thing:[entity_name]. So try with thing:autocarro and thing:bus_auto_2. All entities created by the IoT Agent are prepend with the type of device and ":", in your case "thing:".

Comment: I tryed the way you asked but it keeps getting 404 :\

Comment: Diego, in the config.ini file the IP address of the context broker should be 130.206.80.40 not 127.0.0.1. Can you try python GetEntity.py thing:bus_auto_2 with that config ?

Comment: That's it Carlos! Thank you. But now if i want to target my own context broker what should i do?

Comment: Hi Diego, in the slide 5 at http://www.slideshare.net/FI-WARE/fiware-iotidasintroul20v2 you have the way to create an IDAS service pointing to your ContextBroker. You may add this as an issue in the FIGWAY github and I'll re-write the script to support it in forthcoming sprints ;-)

Comment: Thanks Carlos you've been very helpful :)

Comment: Diego, I have just modified the "CreateService.py" script at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-figway/tree/master/python-IDAS4/Sensors_UL20  . Now you can optionally add an IP and a PORT for your private instance of ContextBroker when creating your IDAS service. Cheers and thanks for using IDAS!

Comment: Carlos, that will definitely improve the use of the service! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry but using your script and providing my ContextBroker Instance (10.133.170.76 1026) when i register the device on the newly created service, i'm not getting the creation of the entities (checked also with GetEntities.py ALL). I changed the config.ini file to work with the service (fiware_soul_2), i've also opened the port 1026 on the firewall.

Comment: Hi Diego, 10.x.y.z seems to be a private IP address. If you are behind a NAT you should be providing a public IP and port and redirect in the NAT that TCP connection to the 10.x.y.z address and port 1026.

Comment: What's happening is that even if i run the script you provided the Context Broker instance that is being accessed to store the entities is always the one in 130.206.80.40.. I configured the config.ini both in CB and in IDAS to run the created service pointing to my own ContextBroker but no matter what it always sticks to the 130.206.80.40 one

Comment: which service are you trying now ? we will check what IDAS is doing and why it goes to that ContextBroker instead of yours.

Comment: I tryied with several services but you can check the "fiware-soul-v3"

Comment: We see it is redirected to some http://188.1??.?2.??4:1026" address (I do not include those numbers for security reasons). We will check if notifications are being sent soon. In the meanwhile, can you check if there is any firewall/NAT misconfiguration ? Thx

Comment: There isn't any firewall misconfiguration. The 1026 is open :-)

Comment: Diogo, I have checked IDAS log and your ContextBroker responds with an error "bad request - tenant name not accepted - a tenant string must not be longer than 50 characters and may only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters". I think the ContextBroker does not like the "-" in the FIWARE service. I would try with "_" or even without them. If that is the case you may report an issue to the ContextBroker team but then we all know this condition.

Comment: Hi Carlos, sorry for the delay in my response. I tried what you sugested but it seems it did not work :( Tell me something, the IDAS ip on the config.ini file is still 130.206.80.40 right? The only thing i need to change is the fiware service?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your script, it seems you are not including the Fiware-Service header in you queryContext request. Thus, the query is resolved in the "default service" and not in bus_auto service.

Probably changing the HEADERS map in the following way would solve the issue:

```
HEADERS = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Fiware-Service: 'bus_auto' 
}
```

**EDIT**: In addition to the above change, note that the BASE_URL is pointint to a local Orion instance, not the one connected with IDAS (which run in the same machine that IDAS). Thus, I think you also need to modify BASE_URL in the following way:

```
BASE_URL = 'http://130.206.80.40:1026'
```

Comment: I updated the script adding the new header but it still doesn't work. I registered another virtual device called "autocarro" and simulated an Observation. Querying the contextBroker it gives me:

404 No context element found

Comment: Maybe BASE_URL has also need to be adjusted. Please see my last edit in the answer post.